# tsquery and tsvector in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, postgresql, tsvector

Can anybody let me know what are the similar functions/datatypes in SQL Server for tsvector and tsquery in Postgresql ?

I am trying to convert a project in to c# and SQL Server which is originally in php+postgresql

Thanks

Comment: Far too much to put in an answer. There's an entire section of documentation on [full text search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)